# Good references for an overview of the Java XML ecosystem?

Tags: java, xml

The java xml ecosystem seems awash in current implementations, API definitions and libraries all with cryptic names. (Web searches frequently turn up references to old/out-of-date implementations as well.)

To list just some of the terms out there (by no means exhaustive): Crimson, Xerces, Xalan, JDOM, Saxon, XOM, JAXP

Are there any good references out there for getting an overview of what libraries and frameworks are currently available and how they compare?

Particular questions it would be helpful for a reference to address:

- What things are part of a standard current java JDK or SDK download?
- What are the dependencies amongst the libraries/frameworks?
- What is current, and what supersedes what?

Comment: Checkout my answer to a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855324/where-i-can-find-a-detailed-comparison-of-java-xml-frameworks/4536265#4536265

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an article ["Choose Your Java XML Parser"](http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/16921) that compares [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/) (Apache), [XDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/xmldevkit/index.html) (Oracle) and [JAXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing) (from Sun, is part of JDK).

Another article is ["XML and Java technologies"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-injava/) from IBM. It compares JDOM, dom4j, EXML, XPP, Crimson and Xerces.

Comment: Loved the article "XML and Java technologies."