# Where I can find a detailed comparison of Java XML frameworks?

Tags: java, xml, architecture, jaxb, xml-parsing

I'm trying to choose an XML-processing framework for my Java projects, and I'm lost in names.. XOM, JDOM, etc. Where I can find a detailed comparison of all popular Java XML frameworks?

Comment: I don't have comparisons...but here's a list of some of the XML processors in Java: http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-parsers

Comment: Note some of those parser projects haven't been active for years.  If you are are interested in object-to-XML binding check out MOXy JAXB (I'm the tech lead), http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Comment: Instead of close consider to migrate to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: A 2019 update https://www.baeldung.com/java-xml-libraries .
This is an old question still relevant in 2021.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As Blaise pointed out stick with the standards. But there are multiple standards created over the period to solve different problems/usecases. Which one to choose completely depends upon your requirement. I hope the below comparison can help you choose the right one.

Now there are **two things** you have to choose. **API** and the **implementations of the API** (there are many)

### API

**SAX: Pros**

- event based
- memory efficient
- faster than DOM
- supports schema validation

**SAX: Cons**

- No object model, you have to tap into
  the events and create your self
- Single parse of the xml and can only
  go forward
- read only api
- no xpath support
- little bit harder to use

**DOM: Pros**

- in-memory object model
- preserves element order
- bi-directional
- read and write api
- xml MANIPULATION
- simple to use
- supports schema validation

**DOM: Cons**

- memory hog for larger XML documents
  (typically used for XML documents
  less than 10 mb)
- slower
- generic model i.e. you work with Nodes

**Stax: Pros**

- Best of SAX and DOM i.e. Ease of DOM
  and efficiency of SAX
- memory efficient
- Pull model
- read and write api
- [supports subparsing](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax-vs-stax.html)
- can read multiple documents same time
  in one single thread
- parallel processing of XML is easier

**Stax: Cons**

- no schema validation support (as far
  as I remember, not sure if they have
  added it now)
- can only go forward like sax
- no xml MANIPULATION

**JAXB: Pros**

- allows you to access and process XML
  data without having to know XML
- bi-directional
- more memory efficient than DOM
- SAX and DOM are generic parsers where
  as JAXB creates a parser specific to
  your XML Schmea
- data conversion: JAXB can convert xml
  to java types
- supports XML MANIPULATION via object
  API

**JAXB: Cons**

- can only parse valid XML

**Trax:** For transforming XML from 1 form to another form using XSLT

### Implementations

SAX, DOM, Stax, JAXB are just specifications. There are many [open source and commercial implementations of these specifications](http://www.edankert.com/jaxpimplementations.html). Most of the time you can just stick with what comes with JDK or your application server. But sometimes you need to use a different implementation that provided by default. And this is where you can appreciate the [JAXP wrapper api](http://jaxp.java.net/). **JAXP** allows you to switch implementations through configuration without the need to modify your code. It also provides a parser/spec independent api for parsing, transformation, validation and querying XML documents.

**Performance and other comparisons of various implementations**

- Stax:
  http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/StAX-1_0.pdf
- Most of the API:
  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-databdopt2/
- JAXB versus XmlBeans discussion on SO: [JAXB vs Apache XMLBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362030/jaxb-vs-apache-xmlbeans)
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-injava/

---

Now standards are good but once in a while you encounter this crazy usecase where you have to support parsing of XML document that is **100 gigabytes** of size or you need **ultra fast** processing of XML (may be your are implementing a XML parser chip) and this is when you need to dump the standards and look for a different way of doing things. Its about using the right tool for the right job! And this is where I suggest you to have a look at [**vtd-xml**](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/)

During the initial days of SAX and DOM, people wanted simpler API's than provided by either of them. [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/), [dom4j](http://www.dom4j.org/), [XmlBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/), [JiBX](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/), [Castor](http://www.castor.org/) are the ones I know that became popular.

Comment: JAXB (JSR-222) implementations do not require an XML schema or compilation step.  Here is an example of starting from Java classes:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Comment: Can the gentleman who has downvoted careto explain the reason pls.

Comment: Don't trust just any implementation! Holy s... have I been f..... just now. Oracle JDK 8 Unit-Test on my local machine parses the String value of an XML-Node like this: 'vyFPEHYkvQNfrR6i', the production system spits out this: [#text: vyFPEHYkvQNfrR6i]. Same source. Crazy!

Answer (score 2):

@`Pangea`

[JAXB vs DOM and SAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709928/jaxb-vs-dom-and-sax)

> JAXB is not directly comparable to DOM and SAX. The Java DOM and SAX
>   parsing APIs are lower-level APIs to parse XML documents, while JAXB
>   (Java API for XML Binding) is a higher-level API for converting XML
>   elements and attributes to a Java object hierarchy (and vice versa).
>   Implementations of JAXB will most likely use a DOM or SAX parser
>   behind the scenes to do the actual parsing of the XML input data.