# SAX Parsing for XML with same name but different content

Tags: xml, parsing, sax, saxparser

I want to use SAX Parsing in Java to parse the xml, which has the following tree structure.

[image: XML Tree Structure]

The issue I am experiencing is that I want to parse elements under

MktgCopy->_x0032_016->X6->Specifications

Since many of the tags have same name, how should I go about this? Is there a way by which I can separate/limit the parsing to a certain section? Any ideas would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: One good way to do this is contenthandler-swapping, described in the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8602001/217324)

Comment: That looks possible. Might get really complicated but lets see. Thanks

Comment: Would you consider using xpath?